# Quotes in powershell and perl one liners

Tags: perl, powershell, quotes

What exactly are the rules for quotes in powershell? Single quotes can contain literal double quotes. Right?

```
PS C:\Users> '"Hello world"'
"Hello world"
PS C:\Users> perl -e 'print \"Heloo World\n\"'
Heloo World
PS C:\Users> perl -e 'print "Heloo World\n"'
PS C:\Users>
```

See? Even after surrounding the command in single quotes, I need to escape those double quotes. What is happening?

Comment: There is only one windows perl version and I think perl itself handles arguments differently due to the restrictions when working under cmd.exe where single quotes have no special meaning

Comment: found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250044/why-is-powershell-with-perl-removing-double-quotes-in-a-simple-print-statement?rq=1) .It seems perl on windows has its own quirks.

Comment: I'd prefer to call it design decisions to have it work under windows, made at a time you couldn't even dream of powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a whole [about page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-6) for Single Quotes vs Double Quotes.

The main take away is that:
1. A string with single quotes can contain double quotes.
2. A string with double quotes can contain single quotes
3. A string with single quotes will take things such as variables and pass them not as the variable, but as the text.

So we setup a string

```
$string = "this is me"
```

And try to print it with double quotes:

```
write-host "who is this? $string"
```

Gives

```
who is this? this is me
```

And if we now try with single quotes:

```
write-host 'who is this? $string'
```

Gives

```
who is this? $string
```

Comment: @TobyU posted a very similar answer,  meanwhile deleted due to downvotes because not related to the question. I'm wondering why you got an upvote.

Comment: Well, the question literally starts with "What exactly are the rules for quotes in PowerShell? That is a question that I try to provide the answer to. If OP does not want that question answered it would be nice that the questions gets edited so it omits posting that question :)

Comment: That's excatly TobyUs answering comment, ignoring the questions title and examples. Once you pass a score of 10k you'll see deleted answers/questions.